# How to animate a weight painting change

Tags: animation, weight-painting, cloth-simulation, vertex-groups

I am trying to achieve this effect in Blender. I have the shape property as a pin group which is the only thing keeping the cloth from falling. I saw somewhere that you can't animate weight painting but it doesn't seem like dynamic painting is helping much either, unless I am doing it wrong.

This is the effect I am trying to achieve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmmKW.jpg

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertex Weight modifiers to adjust softbody/cloth simulation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270428/vertex-weight-modifiers-to-adjust-softbody-cloth-simulation)

Comment: That comment's auto-generated.  Link should give you a start to figuring out how to animate your pinning group.  Note that you may want to combine this with other vertex weight modifiers (proximity, mix) in order to get the precise effect you want.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 4):

Here is my try.

[image: example animation]

You need the following:

- one plane cut into 4 parts
- two vertex groups (Pin and Mask)
- one *Empty* object to control the weights
- one *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier

[image: vertex groups]

The plane was created with two *Array* modifiers. For a better overview, the four parts are separated (that's the shape key). If you have the four parts aligned to each other use X-ray mode to select all vertices that you want because of the "duplicated vertices".

The *Pin Group* is your pin group for the *Cloth* modifier. The *Edit Group (Mask)* contains the vertices that should be affected by the *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier. In my example, all vertices are in the *Pin Group* to make the plane stiff.

[image: screenshot of the modifiers]

Make sure the origin of the plane is in the center (3D Cursor) because when you use the *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier with the *Proximity Mode* `Object` then the distance of the origins (Empty <-> Plane) will be used to calculate the weights.

Comment: I have my scene setup the way that you do but my cloth sim won't stay together at the start before the empty is lowered. I am unsure what I am missing settings wise.

Comment: Have you assigned all vertices to the pin group and have you specified the pin group in the cloth settings?

Answer (score 3):

The principle is pretty simple:

Create 4 planes, subdivide them "enough" so that the cloth simulation can work.

[image]

Give each plane a vertex group like this for pinning:

[image]

Add cloth to all planes and give them the vertex group as pin group.

[image]

Create two cylinders (or whatever you like) and use them to influence your weight of your pin vertex group. So what we actually do is converting the 1 to 0 values from the pin group and by this the cloth can "fall down" or release.
So you can use a vertex weight proximity modifier for this:

[image]

Important: move this modifier before (!) the cloth modifier.
Use geometry as proximity mode.

then you will get:

[image]

[image]